Integral of the radius reciprocal in general dimension $d$
I am deriving an upper bound which ends up with this integral where $\Omega$ is a subset from a convex domain of smoothing boundary. But not sure how to proceed afterwards.
$$
\int_{\Omega} \frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|^{d-1}}  d\mathbf{y}
$$
This integral can be viewed as integrating over the distance between any arbitrary points in the domain and a fixed point $\mathbf{x}$. But I don't see how this is bounded above as $\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|^{d-1}}$ can go to infinity. Can anyone help me on this? Or I have the right conclusion for this integral?

Please give precisions (and example(s)): where is $x$ situated ? On the surface ? In the open volume delimited by the surface ? Is the surface bounded ? Which kind of "subset" of the surface do you consider ? etc.
